# How to make redirect for API POST call request works exactly same like HTML POST request

Tags: php, html, laravel, curl

Below is my code using curl and it's not really redirect like HTML form :

```
$curl =  new \Curl\Curl();
        $curl->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
        $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_POST,true);
        $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $curl->post('http://localpay.sample.test/make-payment',$params);
```

Hi guys,
above are the sample code that I made using  [php package : curl/curl](https://github.com/php-mod/curl) ,

but don't worry,I'm looking forward for any answer,answer using pure curl also can and any other answer also can as long it's working with php language.

What I'm trying to achieve is how to do an API call works exactly the same like HTML form. Why I want to achieve this ? because in the HTML form we need to click the submit button,I know javascript can do the trigger but I'm trying to build my own package with totally back-end language.

I already tried search for the questions on the internet, but none was what I expected.

And below is my simple html form and it does redirect to the desired url :

```
<form id="payment_confirmation" action="http://localpay.sample.test/make-payment" method="post"/>

   Payer ID : <input type="text" name="payer_acc_id"><br>
   Payee ID : <input type="text" name="payer_acc_id"><br>
   <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="somePhpFunction()">

    <button type="submit" value="Submit"> Submit</button>

</form>
```

Above is the sample working HTML form and it's redirect to that action url path but in curl I fail to achieve it, so how do I achieve this by using curl or any other ways also can.

Comment: So the browser makes a request to your PHP which makes a request to localpay. Local pay redirects. Your code should cause PHP to follow the request automatically. Or are you asking how to make the browser visit the URL that curl is redirected to?

Comment: Quentin, html form is working fine, but what happen to curl is it's not redirected to the intended url path

Comment: What makes you think cURL is not being redirected?

Comment: my browser does not redirected to the intended url, and HTML form does redirect the browser to the intended url

Comment: Why should the *browser* be redirected? The request is being made by PHP/cURL, not the browser. Your PHP code has no `header("location: ...")` call in it, so you aren't telling the browser to go to a different URL.

Comment: It do need to be redirect because the intended url path is not my own system, I integrating with another company system and it do need redirect because their system will return the data to my system based on my callback url

Comment: I was not suggesting that you should not desire what you desire, only that your code does absolutely nothing to achieve that desire.

Comment: so how do I achieve it ?

Comment: Five minutes ago I pointed out that you had no `header("location: ...")` call. Add one.

Comment: All right, will give it a try

Comment: How do I achieve this using php curl ? what's the curl option name for that?

Comment: `header` is a PHP function, not a curl option.

Comment: I tried but the method that header redirect function is using is GET method, not POST method

Answer (score 0):

setting the `Content-Type` header does not dictate which format curl will use to send the post data. if you give CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS an array then curl will send the data using the `multipart/form-data` format, regardless of what you put in the Content-Type header. most likely your curl code sends the data in the Multipart/form-data format and $params is an array, and because you tell the server `this is application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the server ties to parse the multipart/form-data data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, 
 (which is a completely incompatible format), and doesn't understand the data at all. if you want to convert an array of post data to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format, use the `http_build_query` function, eg

```
    $curl->post('http://localpay.sample.test/make-payment',http_build_query($params));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for POST redirect using curl :

```
$params = ['payee_id' => 1 , 'amount' => 300];

$curl = curl_init('http://someurl.com/silent/pay');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));    
        curl_exec($curl);
```

curl will follow the redirect for POST method, if you guys want more explanation,go [here](https://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/).